# how do i calculate (and Apply) Loss gradients with respect to the input (not the weights) of a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation, gan, manifold-learning

I have a trained generator, i would like to apply a loss function to the output and optimize the input (latent vector) using a gradient decent optimizer.
i don't know how to calculate the gradients with respect to the input. when using automatic back propagation (in Matlab) for example, the software keeps track of the gradients with respect to the weights. is there a way i can use automatic back propagation?

[image]
thanks

Comment: though i'm not familiar with matlab's backpropagation implementation -- in general yes, you can use backprop (automatic differentiation) to find the gradient wrt to the input.